# Question about the Writer monad as taught in LYAH. (How did the appending to the log take place?)

Tags: haskell, monads, monoids, do-notation, writer-monad

I'm learning Haskell from the "Learn you a Haskell for Great Good" tutorial and I've got to the part on [writer monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer). Here's the example that I can't figure out.

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int  
logNumber x = writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])  

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int  
multWithLog = do  
   a <- logNumber 3  
   b <- logNumber 5  
   return (a*b) -- shouldn't return (3*5) result in (15,[]) ?

ghci> runWriter $ multWithLog
(15,["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"]) -- how did that happen?
```

I am trying understand how the monoidic value `w` in the `Writer w a` monad returned by the `do` block got changed. The tutorial did not go into details on how the `mappend`ing took place.

The type declaration for `Writer` and the instance declaration for `Writer` as a monad is given by the tutorial as

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, w) }  

instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where  
    return x = Writer (x, mempty)
    (Writer (x,v)) >>= f = let (Writer (y, v')) = f x in Writer (y, v `mappend` v')
```

if `return x` results in `Writer (x, mempty)` as per the instance declaration and `mempty` for monoid `[a]` is `[]`, shouldn't `return (a*b)`, which amounts to `return (3*5)`, evaluate to `(15,[])`?

```
ghci> return (15) :: Writer [String] Int
WriterT (Identity (15,[]))
```

I gave the above command to ghci and it returns a `WriterT` type value, the tuple contains an empty list as expected.

```
multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int
multWithLog = logNumber 3 >>= (\a -> 
              logNumber 5 >>= (\b -> 
              return (a*b)))
```

I've rewritten the `do` block using bind operators instead. The above code gave identical result as the original code in the tutorial.

I'm under the impression that `>>=` only extracted `Int` `3` from the result of `logNumber 3` and gave it to `(\a -> logNumber 5 ...etc.)`, which then did the `logNumber` function on a different value (`5`) and so on. How did these operations lead to the `[String]` part of the Writer monad being altered?

Comment: I think you might be confused about what `return` means in Haskell - which is pretty common, so don't feel bad about it. In most imperative languages a `return x` at the bottom of a function definition means that the result of the function is `x`. But `return` in Haskell is just a function, and the actual value of `multWithLog` is the expression obtained from evaluating that entire `do` block, not just the last line with `return`. In particular the successive lines of the `do` block are connected by applications of `>>=`, and it is this which appends the log values "behind the scenes".

Comment: "I'm under the impression that >>= only extracts Int 3 ...". That's where you are wrong. Only 3 is passed as the *argument* to the next function, but `m >>= f` doesn't simply return whatever `f` returns. It creates a *new* Writer value using both `m` and the return value of `f`.

Answer (score 3):

From the code you posted

```
(Writer (x,v)) >>= f =
   let (Writer (y, v')) = f x in Writer (y, v `mappend` v')
```

we can see that indeed `f` is being called only with the `x` argument.
So in `logNumber 3 >>= \a -> ...` variable `a` indeed is bound to `3`.

However, `>>=` does something after calling `f`, namely it combines `v` with `v'`. In your example, `v` is the `[String]` coming from `logNumber 3` which is `["Got number: 3"]`. Instead `v'` comes form evaluating `\a -> ...` with `a=3`, and is `["Got number: 5"]`.

`mappend` for lists is `++`, which concatenates the lists together. Hence we get the final result.

Allow me to be a little sloppy and neglect the `Writer` wrappers. We get

```
return (a*b)
= (a*b, [])

logNumber 5 >>= \b -> return (a*b) 
= logNumber 5 >>= \b -> (a*b, [])
= (5, ["Got number: 5"]) >>= \b -> (a*b, [])
= (a*5, ["Got number: 5"] `mappend` [])
= (a*5, ["Got number: 5"])

logNumber 3 >>= \a -> logNumber 5 >>= \b -> return (a*b)
= logNumber 3 >>= \a -> (a*5, ["Got number: 5"])
= (3, ["Got number: 3"]) >>= \a -> (a*5, ["Got number: 5"])
= (3*5, ["Got number: 3"] `mappend` ["Got number: 5"])
= (15, ["Got number: 3", "Got number: 5"])
```

Intuitively, we can pretend that a value in your writer monad is an effectful computation, which returns a value (like `3`) and as a side effect appends a few messages to a list-of-strings. The log of all such messages is invisible inside the monad (we can only append to the log), and will only be made available at the very end, when we will use `runWriter` to exit from the monadic context.

Answer (score 2):

This ought to explain it:

```
> runWriter (return 15) :: (Int, [String])
(15,[])                       -- == runWriter $ writer (15, mempty)

> runWriter (logNumber 3)
(3,["Got number: 3"])         -- == runWriter $ writer (3, ["Got number: 3"])

> runWriter (logNumber 5)
(5,["Got number: 5"])         -- == runWriter $ writer (5, ["Got number: 5"])

> runWriter (logNumber 3 >> logNumber 5)
(5,["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"])   -- == ["Got number: 3"] ++ ["Got number: 5"]

> runWriter (logNumber 3 >>         logNumber 5 >>         return 15        )
(15,["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"])  -- == ["Got number: 3"] ++ ["Got number: 5"] ++ []

> runWriter (logNumber 3 >>= (\_ -> logNumber 5 >>= (\_ -> return 15    ) ) )
(15,["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"])

> runWriter (logNumber 3 >>= (\i -> logNumber 5 >>= (\j -> return (i*j) ) ) )
(15,["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"])
```

And the last line's monadic expression is equivalent to `multWithLog`'s `do` block.

Noice the *nesting* of the lambda functions: the lambda function

```
                                                    (\j -> return (i*j) )
```

is situated *inside* the lambda function

```
                             (\i -> logNumber 5 >>= (\j -> return (i*j) ) )
```

That's why the `i` in that `return (i*j)` refers to the *outer* lambda function's argument `i`, received by it from the outermost monadic action expression, `logNumber 3`.

How? Because *according to the definition of `>>=`* as you quote it in your question, we have

```
   runWriter ( Writer (x,v) >>= f )
=
   runWriter ( let (Writer (y, u)) = f x in Writer (y, v `mappend` u) )
= 
   let (Writer (y, u)) = f x in runWriter ( Writer (y, v `mappend` u) )
= 
   let (Writer (y, u)) = f x in (y, v `mappend` u)
```

i.e.

```
   runWriter ( logNumber 5 >>= (\j -> return j) )
=                              -------- f -----
   runWriter ( writer (5, ["Got number: 5"]) >>= (\j -> writer (j, mempty)) )
=                  --  x  ------- v -------      -------- f ---------------
   let Writer (y, u) = ( (\j -> writer (j, mempty)) 5 ) 
                         -------- f --------------- x
                            in (y, ["Got number: 5"] `mappend` u) 
=                                  ------- v ------- 
   let (y, u) = (5, mempty) in (y, ["Got number: 5"] `mappend` u) 
=
                               (5, ["Got number: 5"] `mappend` mempty)
```

The "monoidic values" from each `Writer` action do *not* "get changed". Each action *contributes* its "monoidic value" into the overall "monoidic value" of the combined `Writer`-type computation of the `do` block, built from its `Writer`-type sub-computations by `mappending` the monoidic values contributed by each sub-computation (the ***semantics*** of `Writer`), found in the `snd` field of the tuples representing the actions (the ***implementation*** of `Writer`).

Again, this overall value is combined by combining the monoidic value parts of each tuple, namely, their `snd` fields. The monoidic combination is `mappend`, which is done behind the scenes for us by the `Writer` type computations.

And for lists, `mappend [a] [b] == [a] ++ [b] == [a,b]`, while `mappend [a,b] [] == [a,b] ++ [] == [a,b]`.

Your questions, then:

- > shouldn't `return (a*b)`  amount to `(15,[])`?

  it should, and it does, as we saw at the start of the answer.
- > `Writer` vs. `WriterT` wrappers

  it doesn't matter. Both are isomorphic, because `Identity` is a no-op. `WriterT` is part of [monad-transformers](/questions/tagged/monad-transformers) implementation of Writer monad; the one given in the book is simpler and easier to follow.
- > How did these operations lead to the `[String]` part of the Writer monad being altered?

  not altered, but combined, by the `mappend` of the specific Monoid used by the specific Writer; as part of the *monadic combination* i.e. the monadic bind's, `>>=`, definition; being as Monads generalize function call protocol and Writer Monad's generalization is collecting a Monoid values behind the scenes, so they can be appended in the shadows, in addition to the user functions doing their work in the open:

  ```
   do { a <- logNumber 3  
      ; b <- logNumber 5  
      ; return (a*b)
      }
  =    ----- user area ------       ---- hidden area ---
   do {  a       <- writer (3       , ["Got number: 3"]       )
      ;    b     <- writer (5       , ["Got number: 5"]       )  
      ;             writer (
        (a*b)                       , []                      )
      }
  =
   Writer
      ( (3*5)                       , mconcat [..., ..., ...] )
  ```

Embrace `do`-notation, it's your friend. It helps us think *abstractly*.