# How does this trick type-check?

Tags: haskell, types, typechecking, do-notation

Reading this blog post – https://www.haskellforall.com/2021/05/the-trick-to-avoid-deeply-nested-error.html – I realised I don't understand why the 'trick' actually works in this situation:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

import Text.Read (readMaybe)

data Person = Person { age :: Int, alive :: Bool } deriving (Show)

example :: String -> String -> Either String Person
example ageString aliveString = do
    age <- case readMaybe ageString of
        Nothing  -> Left "Invalid age string"
        Just age -> pure age

    if age < 0
        then Left "Negative age"
        else pure ()

    alive <- case readMaybe aliveString of
        Nothing    -> Left "Invalid alive string"
        Just alive -> pure alive

    pure Person{ age, alive }
```

Specifically I'm struggling to understand why this bit

```
    if age < 0
        then Left "Negative age"
        else pure ()
```

type checks.

`Left "Negative age"` has a type of `Either String b`

while

`pure ()` is of type `Either a ()`

Why does this work the way it does?

---

EDIT: I simplified and re-wrote the code into bind operations instead of `do` block, and then saw Will's edit to his already excellent answer:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

import           Text.Read (readMaybe)

newtype Person = Person { age :: Int} deriving (Show)

example :: String -> Either String Person
example ageString =
    getAge ageString
    >>= (\age -> checkAge age
        >>= (\()-> createPerson age))

getAge :: Read b => String -> Either [Char] b
getAge ageString = case readMaybe ageString of
       Nothing  -> Left "Invalid age string"
       Just age -> pure age

checkAge :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Either [Char] ()
checkAge a = if a < 0
       then Left "Negative age"
       else pure ()

createPerson :: Applicative f => Int -> f Person
createPerson a = pure Person { age = a }
```

I think this makes the 'trick' of passing the `()` through binds much more visible - the values are taken from an outer scope, while `Left` indeed short-circuits the processing.

Comment: Pretty sure there is a formal argument that `Either String Person` is a subtype of both `Either a ()` and `Either String b`, but I failed to make it in my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: I.e., `Left "Invalid alive string"` can be treated as a value of type `Either String b` no matter what type you choose for `b`, because no value of type `b` is used in the value.

Comment: @chepner it doesn't have to be `Either String Person`, `Either String anything` is enough. It's in the _middle_ of the do block, and there's no value "extraction". :) so it serves as a guard.

Comment: @WillNess But the definition of `>>=` for `Either a` means it will be used as the return value. `pure ()` only type checks because it's not the last expression in the `do` block.

Comment: @chepner "_it_ will be used as the return value" you mean `String`? it's not "value", it's part of the "shell": in `Either String b`, `Either String` is the vessel (so, in  `Either` "language", `String` is the "error signal"), `b` is the contents / value. of course the reified computation `Either String b` is a value itself, but we treat it as computation denotation, mentally.

Comment: No, the value `Left "foo"`. On its *own*, it's a value of type `forall a. Either String a`, but it needs to be a value of type `Either String Person` to be used as the return value of `example`. I thought the question was how the value can have both types.

Comment: @chepner but it's _not_ the _last_ value, so it only needs to be `Either String _`.

Comment: It *effectively* is the last value, as the rest of the block won't be evaluated, since `Left x >>= _ == Left x`.

Comment: @chepner ah, yes, but *no*: it's ***not*** `l@(Left x) >>= _ = l` ! the `Left x`  on the right creates a _new_ value, of _another_ type, `Either String Person` indeed! (using the same `x`, hence it _had_ to be `Either String _` (writing informally)). it's not the same value having two types, it's two values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It typechecks because `Either String b` and `Either a ()` unify successfully, with `String ~ a` and `b ~ ()`:

```
     Either String b
     Either a      ()
   ------------------
     Either String ()      a ~ String, b ~ ()
```

It appears in the `do` block of type `Either String Person`, so it's OK, since it's the same monad, `Either`, with the same "error signal" type, `String`.

It appears in the *middle* of the `do` block, and there's no value "extraction".  So it serves as a guard.

It goes like this: if it was `Right y`, then the `do` block's translation is

```
      Right y >>= (\ _ -> .....)
```

and the computation continues inside `.....` with the `y` value ignored. But if it was `Left x`, then

```
      Left x >>= _  =  Left x
```

according to the definition of `>>=` for `Either`. Crucially, the `Left x` on the right is ***not*** the same value as `Left x` on the left. The one on the left has type `Either String ()`; the one on the right has type `Either String Person` indeed, as demanded by the return type of the `do` block overall.

The two `Left x` are *two* different values, each with its own specific type. The `x :: String` is the same, of course.

Comment: Ah I get it now! I think. So as it's in the middle of the do block, the type of the `if` block doesn't have to match the function return type, as it's piped into another function?

Comment: @larek, yes, but the two `if` branches still have to match.  And here they do, because one can have anything on the left, and the other can have anything on the right.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! Took me to rewrite it with binds (see edit) to properly internalise what's going on

Comment: By which I mean: `do` blocks are hard on my brain

Comment: @Iarek [do notation is our friend](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+%5Bdo-notation%5D+friend). it is there to help us. of course first we must work through the particular type's `>>=` code closely, to see exactly what is going on. but then it helps us _separate the concerns_ -- one realm is the machinations in the computation pipeline, the other is what we the programmer are doing.

Comment: @Iarek regarding your edit: see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727803/does-the-main-function-in-haskell-always-start-with-main-do/44728131#44728131. we can always write `do { ... <- ...... ; .... }`, and use `_` or `()` as needed on the left of the *"from"* arrow. re my mention of two "realms", see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398338/question-about-the-writer-monad-as-taught-in-lyah-how-did-the-appending-to-the/55439614#55439614) (look closer to the end of the answer).