# Why do I need to call the constructor again in the definition of fmap even when I don't apply the f argument?

Tags: haskell, functor, algebraic-data-types, sum-type

I have no idea why `fmap _ a = a` below is illegal. Here is the code:

```
data Sum a b = First a | Second b

instance Functor (Sum a) where
  fmap f (Second b) = Second (f b)
  fmap _ (First a)  = First a
  fmap _ a          = a  -- Why can't I do this instead?
```

Other question is, does this have performance penalty implications or is something that happens only at compile time?

Comment: If you have a `s :: Sum Int Int` and you do `fmap show s`, what should happen, according to your implementation?

Comment: It's just an exercise for a book, but it should behave like Either.

Comment: assuming you have an `f : b -> c` then `fmap f a` is supposed to result in a `Sum a c` - but `a :: Sum a b` - see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the constructor *anew*  to create a *new* value, so it will have a different type than the one you've started with.

```
fmap ::   (b -> c) ->    Sum a b  -> Sum a c
fmap (f :: b -> c) ::    Sum a b  -> Sum a c
fmap (f :: b -> c) (x :: Sum a b) -> Sum a c

                 a ::     a               a ::     a
           First a :: Sum a b       First a :: Sum a c

                 b ::       b             c ::       c
          Second b :: Sum a b      Second c :: Sum a c
```

Given `a :: a`, `First a` has type `Sum a t` with `t` determined by the context in which `First a` appears. The two `First a` on both sides of the equal sign define two different values, each of its own type. Using the variable `a` on the right, it still refers to the same value of type `Sum a b` as it is on the left. But we need a different type, according to `fmap`.

Comment: I thought I answered some very similar question recently, but couldn't find it.

Comment: [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67522395/how-does-this-trick-type-check/67522546#67522546).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding performance: quite late in the compilation process, when GHC has erased most type information, it does its best to notice when a value is being reconstructed like that. This step catches a lot of situations, but not all; sometimes the code will have been transformed in such a manner that the reconstruction is no longer obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do this is because the result type of `fmap` depends on the result type of `f`, but the expression `a` does not.   That is to say, you do not have the constraint `f b ~ a`.

Comment: That's was a simple and strait to the point answer, thanks!